# is there any way to create Onclick event while program is on?

Tags: vb.net

I want when I click on link label it give me the name of the textbox which in the same line in a variable named AA
`

```
    Dim serial As Integer = 1
    Public Function addnewline()
        Dim lbl As New System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
        Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

        ' add label
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
        lbl.Top = serial * 27
        lbl.Left = 100
        lbl.Text = Me.serial
        lbl.Name = "lbl" & Me.serial

        ' add textbox
        Me.Controls.Add(txt)
        txt.Top = serial * 27
        txt.Left = 200
        txt.Height = 500
        txt.Width = 100
        txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        txt.Text = "text" & Me.serial
        txt.Name = "txt" & Me.serial

        serial += 1
        Return lbl
        Return txt

    End Function
```

`
here is a gif for my code
[image]

Comment: [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified a bit. Function is now a sub

```
Dim Serial As Integer = 1
Dim AA As String = ""
Public Sub AddNewline()
    Dim lbl As New System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
    Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    ' add label
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    lbl.Top = Serial * 27
    lbl.Left = 100
    lbl.Text = Me.Serial
    lbl.Name = "lbl" & Me.Serial

    ' add textbox
    Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    txt.Top = Serial * 27
    txt.Left = 200
    txt.Height = 500
    txt.Width = 100
    txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    txt.Text = "text" & Me.Serial
    txt.Name = "txt" & Me.Serial

    AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf Label_Click

    Serial += 1
    'Return lbl
    'Return txt
End Sub

Private Sub Label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    AA = ""
    Dim Lbl As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    If Lbl IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim Idx As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Lbl.Name, "[^\d]", "")
        If Idx <> "" Then
            If Me.Controls.Find("txt" & Idx, True).Count = 1 Then
                Dim T As TextBox = Me.Controls.Find("txt" & Idx, True)(0)
                AA = T.Text
                ' or
                TextBoxYellow.Text = AA
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

We want two changes: set the textbox to the label's `.Tag` property, and use `AddHandler` for the click event. While I'm here I'm also going to fix a few other things that didn't make sense (only one return is allowed, and even that was not needed) and reduce flickering:

```
Dim serial As Integer = 1

Public Sub addnewline()
    'Textbox
    Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    txt.Top = serial * 27
    txt.Left = 200
    txt.Height = 500
    txt.Width = 100
    txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    txt.Text = "text" & Me.serial
    txt.Name = "txt" & Me.serial

    'Label 
    Dim lbl As New System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
    lbl.Top = serial * 27
    lbl.Left = 100
    lbl.Text = Me.serial
    lbl.Name = "lbl" & Me.serial.ToString()
    ' Next two lines are new
    lbl.Tag = txt 
    AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf labelClick

    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    Me.ResumeLayout()

    serial += 1
End Sub

Public Sub labelClick(sender As Control, e As EventHandler)
    Dim txt As TextBox = TryCast(sender.Tag, TextBox)
    If txt IsNot Nothing Then
        AA.Text = txt.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

While I'm here, **you should really turn on Option Strict!**

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `AddHandler`, like this:

```
 Dim serial As Integer = 1
 Dim AA As String = ""

Public Function addnewline()
    Dim lbl As New System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
    Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    ' add label
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    lbl.Top = serial * 27
    lbl.Left = 100
    lbl.Text = Me.serial
    lbl.Name = "lbl" & Me.serial
    
    ' add textbox
    Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    txt.Top = serial * 27
    txt.Left = 200
    txt.Height = 500
    txt.Width = 100
    txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    txt.Text = "text" & Me.serial
    txt.Name = "txt" & Me.serial

    AddHandler lbl.Click, Sub ()
        AA = txt.Name
        MessageBox.Show(AA)
    End Sub
    serial += 1

    Return lbl
    Return txt
End Function
```

Comment: That's great, but the primary case that the OP is used to is setting up a method to handle events. Perhaps you could show that? Also, there's very little explanation as to what's going on with your code. And you don't make it clear how to remove a handler - and that's especially important when adding anonymous methods.